What is the difference between Generic method and Interface as an parameter in method?
interface Size {
}

class Triangle implements Size {
}

class Rectangle implements Size {
}


public <I extends Size> method1(I input) {
    System.out.println(input)
}

public void method2(Size s) {
    System.out.println(input)
}

main() {
    method1(new Triangle());
    method2(new Rectangle());
}

What is the difference between method1 and method2 when method2 is working with all the classes that are implementing Size interface?
I have checked these two method are working same but if they are same then what is the purpose of creating these scenarios.

There doesn‘t seem to be any point in using generics here. Declaring the parameter to be a Size is simple and gives us what we want. One now and then sees code that overuses generics in this way.

The given code isn't valid Java as the method declarations lack return types. Assuming you implicitly meant them to be void, there really is no upside in declaring method1 as a generic method.
Usually, the benefit of such declarations is by allowing you to specify that the return value matches the passed type, e.g.:
public <I extends Size> I enlarge(I input) {
    // Returns the same type as was passed, allowing you to do
    // Triangle small = new Triangle();
    // Triangle big = enlarge(small)

or that several arguments have the same type:
public <I extends Size> void chain(I input1, I input2) {
    // The definition of I ensures you'd be chaining objects of the same type


It's void by mistake i haven't added. Can you please provide code snippet which can distinguish method1 and method2

There are some syntax related issues in the code.

the keyword piblic should be public

sout should be System.out.println()

if Size is an interface it should be declared as:
interface Size{
}



Method1 is called as generic method in which you are using generic Type I, which extends the Size interface. this method can operate on any type that implements size interface while maintaing the exact argument types.

Method2 using the interface as a parameter simply takes objects of type size. this means the method can accept any class that implements size but it treats the parameter as just type size. you loose the ability to interact with type specific methods or behaviors of the actual class like (Triangle/Rectangle) since the reference is of type Size


So, both methods work similarly but method1 provides more type-specific advantages.

I fail to see the truth of this. How would you interact with type specific methods or behaviors in the generic method when all you know is that the parameter has type I and I extends Size?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
